# Infinite recurrence using \in

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

I am unable to understand the following occurrence:

```
\[ f_{i}(x_{1}^{*}(t), x_{2}^{*}(t), x_{3}^{*}(t), p(t)) = 0 \;\; \text{$\forall$ i\in\{1,..., n\}} \]
```

[image]

Comment: There is no need to use the `\text` command and your usage is incorrect.

Comment: What's your question? Is your question about the typesetting or markup? If so, then it's appropriate to ask here. Like Stephen I wouldn't use `\text` at all, which would mean there's no need for the `$` around `\forall`; if you want the `i` variable to be upright, I'd use `\mathup{i}`. If your question is about how to interpret the formula, or the mathematics behind it, you'd want to ask in the [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Assuming your question is that "why does the output becomes like that" -- your code does not give that result, the bug is somewhere else. -- Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.